# xhtml2pdf - Set word spacing

Tags: html, pdf, xhtml2pdf

Is there any way to set spacing between words in `xhtml2pdf` besides using `&nbsp;`? I am trying `style="word-spacing: 30px;"` but it is probably not supported.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#supported-css-properties). Maybe you need to use `white-space` instead of `word-space`.

Comment: @AhmerMH that is basically the same as doing `&nbsp;`. I don't want to add spaces manually everywhere

Comment: Looking at their documentation, there seems to be no way to add the word spacing, however, a workaround can be to enclose each word in a span/ div and use a `margin-left` or `margin-right` on them. There is one property defined `pdf:spacer ` but there is no documentation about it. Hope it helps!